# POST JSON data via CURL and grabbing it

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to pass a json data as param for cURL POST. However, I am stuck at grabbing it and saving it on db.

cURL file:

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$url = 'http://localhost/project/test_curl';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                                    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                                           
                                    );                       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                                                     

$result = curl_exec($ch);  

//based on http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl
```

test_curl file:

```
    $order_info = $_POST; // this seems to not returning anything

    //SAVE TO DB... saving empty...
```

What did I miss? Weew....

Comment: As mentioned in your tutorial link you have to add the content length parameter as an additional header. I can ensure that this tutorial totally works (I used it for myself 2 days ago). If that does not work maybe the designed target of the curl request does not have the expected behaviour.

Comment: By the way, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS need an associative array to post, like array('data' => $data_string) otherwise it won't post anything

Comment: @DieVarDump That is not true. It accepts a string or an associative array. If you want to use `Content-Type: application/json` it *must* be a string. It is better to create the string yourself and pass that, because if you pass an array the `Content-Type` will be `multipart/form-data` and the request body will likely be much larger than it would be if you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @DaveRandom yes, my mistake, i didn't see the HTTPHEADER... forget about my previous comment.

Comment: @TRD Yes... I just got confused on handling JSON post and just mentioned in my question where I get my example. Just sayin' there is no problem with the tutorial... it's me having a problem grasping it. :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are sending the data as raw JSON in the body, it will not populate the `$_POST` variable.

You need to do one of two things:

1. You can change the content type to one that will populate the `$_POST` array
2. You can read the raw body data.

I would recommend option two if you have control over both ends of the communication, as it will keep the request body size to a minimum and save bandwidth over time. (*Edit: I didn't really emphasize here that the amount of bandwidth it will save is negligible, only a few bytes per request, this would only be a valid concern is very high traffic environments. However I still recommend option two because it is the cleanest way*)

In your `test_curl` file, do this:

```
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$rawData = stream_get_contents($fp);

$postedJson = json_decode($rawData);

var_dump($postedJson);
```

If you want to populate the `$_POST` variable, you will need to change the way you send the data to the server:

```
$data = array (
  'name' => 'Hagrid',
  'age' => '36'
);

$bodyData = array (
  'json' => json_encode($data)
);
$bodyStr = http_build_query($bodyData);

$url = 'http://localhost/project/test_curl';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Length: '.strlen($bodyStr)
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodyStr);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The raw, undecoded JSON will now be available in `$_POST['json']`.

Comment: I did option two. Thank you very much! It worked and you did explain it well... wooow I did miss a lot. Again, thanks!

Comment: thx for this details, Does the GET works the same with those 2 content types?

Comment: @ciril A GET request has no content, and therefore no `content-type`. If you wan't to pass JSON via GET (which I don't recommend, by the way) you need to append it to the URL. For example `$url = 'http://example.com/script.php?json='.urlencode(json_encode($data));` - the data will then be available in `$_GET['json']` at the other end.

Comment: right, so I can also remove in my code curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader); when performing a get probably, thx

Comment: If all the headers are related to content, probably yes. Although to be honest I think cURL is pretty intelligent when it comes to inspecting the headers before use - I doubt it would break if you leave them in.

Comment: other q: Is it necessary to do $data[$name] = **urlencode**($value) before curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); or is it redundant?

Comment: @ciril `http_build_query()` automatically url-encodes data. If you pass it through `urlencode()` as well, it will get double encoded and break the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use following php function for posting data using php curl function in x-www-form-urlencoded format.

```
<?php
    $bodyData = http_build_query($data); //for x-www-form-urlencoded
?>
```

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//$SITEURL$/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.