# PHP Forwarding JSON Object

Tags: php, json

For security reasons I have to forward a JSON Object from a Jquery Script to a PHP Script. Here is what I have done yet:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$content = json_encode( $input );

$url = $_GET["trakt_url"]."KEY";

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

If I log the $content I get the JSON Object but the page($url) at where I post to is getting an empty Object. Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Solved** (someone answered correctly but the answer is deleted?!)

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "json=$content");**

Comment: Set the content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the content-length in the request header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content))                                                                       
);
```

You will also need to make sure POSTFIELDS is defined as a urlencoded string, since setting it as an array will override the content-type to `multipart/form-data`. This will work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "json=$content");
```

Comment: @SimonSchubert Also try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9062145/427992)