# crossrider how to collect post data with php

Tags: php, javascript, post, curl, crossrider

So I am finding it difficult to post data to my php server. It seems to work from the crossrider end of things, but I am not sure what to use to collect the post with `PHP`. 
Here is the crossrider code borrowed from the docs page:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
// Posting data using a JSON object
appAPI.request.post({
    url: 'http://ultimarks.arcco96.c9.io/service.php',
    // Data to post
    postData: ["hello","world"],
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        //alert("Succeeded in posting data");
        //alert(response);
    },
    onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        //alert('Failed to retrieve content. (HTTP Code:' + httpCode + ')');
    },
    additionalRequestHeaders: {
        myHeader: 'value'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
});
```

and this is my php code:

```
print_r($_post);
```

It returns Array() on both the php page and in an alert generated by crossrider (which is strange because I never programmed that).

Perhaps the problem is that I am trying to print something to a `PHP` page that's not a redirect from a form.

So how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Variables in PHP are case-sensitive. The correct PHP variable is `$_POST` not `$_post`

Comment: that didnt change anything

Comment: ah- second problem. According to the crossrider documentation, your postData needs to be either a string or an object. Right now, it's an array. Try either `"hello=world"` or `{"hello":"world"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
var data1 = "Mydata1";
var data2 = "Mydata2";
appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {   
    appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/Ext.php',
        postData: 'data1='+ data1 +'&data2='+ data2,
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            alert("Succeeded in posting data");
            //alert(response);
        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
            alert('in posting data. (HTTP Code:' + httpCode + ')');
        },
        additionalRequestHeaders: {
            myHeader: 'value'
        },
        // contentType: 'application/json'
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
}); });
```

Then, in the Ext.php file grab the post data using $_POST["data1"] and $_POST["data2"]

Sample code for $_POST[]:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

PHP $_POST global variable does not get populated from JSON payload in requests. So, either you send data in x-www-form-urlencoded as retailcoder is suggesting, or modify the way your php scripts reads the input, as found here: [POST JSON data via CURL and grabbing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062060/post-json-data-via-curl-and-grabbing-it)