# Keep getting 400 error with cURL on localhost

Tags: php, json, curl

I've been scouring around trying to understand curl and building headers but it seems no matter what I do I get the following error :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 18:15:33 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 Content-Length: 226 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

The following is the function that I am using to send post variables and fetch the contents via curl. Both the file doing the fetching and the file whose contents are fetched are being hosted locally on MAMP

```
    $url = "./lib/otherpage.php";
    $data = array("url"=>$_POST["url"],"format"=>"json");
    function tryCurl($baseurl,$data)
    {
        $bodydata = array(json_encode($data));
        $bodystr = http_build_query($bodydata);

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$baseurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$bodystr);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,8888);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            "POST / HTTP/1.0",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($bodystr),
            "Host: localhost:8888/gt_dev/",
            "User-Agent: My-User-Agent 1.0",
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Accept-Language: en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3",
            "Connection: close",
        ));

        // Execute
        $result=curl_exec($ch);

        // Printing any errors..
        echo curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Ultimately, the request should send two post variables ("url" and "format") to the receiving file, and expect a json string in return.

Comment: have you tryied the full url path?

Comment: You're trying to do too much with the headers, and also, `$bodydata = array(json_encode($data)); $bodystr = http_build_query($bodydata);` is totally broken.

Comment: @AguV The full url path yields the same result. drew010 - Yeah, I don't know how it's supposed to work as I've tried everything. The code you're referring to I pulled from the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062060/post-json-data-via-curl-and-grabbing-it)

Comment: what are you trying to do with $_POST["url"] ? make certain your `$data` is not `null`.

Comment: Are you trying to send json or form-urlencoded? Check your $bodydata variable!

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I'm trying to pass the post variable I'm receiving in this file (which I've checked and it's not null) to other page. Same error. And If I update the following :

    $bodydata = array($data);
    $bodystr = http_build_query($data);

Then I just get a "malformed" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't so much an answer to the original issue but turns out I was thinking about my problem the wrong way.

I wanted to use page A as a proxy to page B. And to pass the same variables page B expected from Page A.

Turns out the same effect can be achieved by simply including page B, not curling the expected parameters to it. So the answer is just

```
include("./lib/otherpage.php");
```